# How to resume kickstart in RedHat ?

Tags: linux

How to resume kickstart in Red Hat ?
I got an error, I just want to re-run and see if we can fix it .

Regards

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it's not possible, you need to reboot.

Comment: Yup, just reboot... unless it has stopped because of missing packages - sometimes you can retry that if you don't have to update the repo metadata etc.